# how to upload excel and find value in one schema and save object id in other schema

Tags: node.js

Suppose I have a upload button and that button can upload excel sheet, find the value one schema and save the value in other schema.

The code will take the `company_name` from excel and find the value from entity `company_name` and save the object Id in entity.
How it will happened if someone help?

```
{
    entity: [{type: Schema.types.Object Id}]
}

{
    entity: string,
    company_name: string,
    company_mobile: string,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use csvtojson package.

import csv from "csvtojson";

//parse request

parseRequestAndConvertCSVtoJSON = async (file) => {

```
//get actual file name from file array
let fileName = file.filename.replace(/\s/g, "");

//uploaded file path
let filePath = basedir + `/uploads/${fileName}`;
    
// Async / await usage
const jsonArray = await csv().fromFile(filePath);

//delete file from folder
fs.unlinkSync(filePath);

//redirect complete URL
return jsonArray;
```

};

And after this run a for of loop and store the data in loop

```
for(let element of data){ const object = {name: element.company_name}; let newCompany = new companyModel(object); company = await newCompany.save();}
```

Comment: i don't want to save in data base i have to find the field in schema the data is exist or not if it is exist then i will take the objectid and then i have a relational schema where i have to save the object id of the entity id

Comment: @Kashif cool then use - let response = await companyModel.findOne({name: element.company_name}).lean();
let objectId = response ? response._id : null;